# Redirect new print jobs to another queue in CUPS

Tags: cups

We're running CUPS with about 10 different printers, and recently one of them started to jam. While we wait for tech support to bless us with a repair, is there a way to redirect all jobs from say Printer 1 to just print to Printer 2?

I know that I can use `lpmove` to move individual jobs, but I'd rather have something put into place to just automatically forward jobs until the printer is replaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably an easier method, but what I did in a similar situation was to rename the printer, create a printer class with the same name and put inside the printer class the printer where you want the jobs redirected.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel up to reconfiguring the printer twice, you can tell the bodgy printer that it's an IPP printer pointing to the other CUPS printer you want to redirect to.  Only hassle is that you have to reconfigure it back to point at the real printer once tech support sorts itself out.